# Remember close state of a jQuery popup modal, is localStorage the easiest way to do? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage to remember user selections when they click on "Stay at International". That way, the popup won't keep prompting whenever the user visits the page.

I couldn't find a way to remember a close state of the jQuery modal and put it into localStorage cookies. Your help will be much appreciated!

```
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div id="countryModal" NAME="country" class="modal">
<a rel="modal:close" href="#" onclick="gotoInternational()">Stay at International</a>
</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('#countryModal').fadeIn('slow').modal('show');
},3000)

function gotoInternational(){
//localStorage codes here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question!
If I were you I would research localStorage a bit more. You are completely correct storing the value in the localStorage is the best way.
If I understand correctly what you want to do your code should look like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div id="countryModal" NAME="country" class="modal">
    <a rel="modal:close" href="#" onclick="gotoInternational()">Stay at International</a>
</div>

<script>
    //Get current localStorage value
    const gotoInternationalValue = localStorage.getItem('gotoInternational');
    //Check if it is not true (can be false or null)
    if (gotoInternationalValue != 'true') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#countryModal').fadeIn('slow').modal('show');
        }, 3000)
    } else {
        console.log("Stay at international was already selected");
    }


    function gotoInternational() {
        //Save localStorage item as true
        localStorage.setItem('gotoInternational', true);
    }
</script>
```

If this is not what you need please add more information to your question to clarify it!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

Your solution is right just that you missed a single quote at here:
if (gotoInternationalValue != **'true'**)

Anyway thanks for your input! Saved my day!

Comment: I edited my response accordingly, could you please flag it as a correct answer! Thanks

Comment: Sure! Thanks mate :)